# Better way of accepting variations of ‘Yes’ from a shell prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, prompt

Usability testing of a shell script I wrote found that people had different expectations on how to answer a question that expected ‘yes’ as the answer. See variations in the below code example.

Surely there must be a better way that what I came up with? What is your *readable* and *shorter form* take on this?

```
read -p 'Answer this question with yes: ' answer
if [ "$answer" = 'Y'
  -o "$answer" = 'YES'
  -o "$answer" = 'Yes'
  -o "$answer" = 'y'
  -o "$answer" = 'yes'
  -o some-alternate-condition ]; then

  echo 'Surely this can be written better?'
fi
```

Comment: Voted to close. While I'm interested in the question, it's probably more of a programming question, so should be on SO.

Comment: A programming answer might be something like [Bash: Check if array element exists](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Check_if_array_element_exists)

Comment: @phunehehe: I disagree with moving to SO, not only because we have a history of accepting shell programming, but also because it's not just a question of how to do it but also a question of what the spec should be.

Comment: I wrote a script much like that once.  Then the program was translated to French and Simplified Chinese.  I skimmed the French version and saw my prompt was translated to "Enter oui or non" but of course the code still wanted "Y*" or "N*"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using a `case` is somewhat equivalent but not perfect since statements like `YE` are accepted.

```
read -p 'Answer this question with yes: ' answer
case "${answer}" in
    [yY]|[yY][eE][sS])
        echo 'Surely this can be written better?' ;;
esac
```

Comment: I would say the user’s intent is pretty clear from ‘ye’.

Answer (score 49):

The UNIX standard provides example code for this using the [`locale` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/locale.html):

```
if printf "%s\n" "$response" | grep -Eq "$(locale yesexpr)"
then
    affirmative processing goes here
else
    non-affirmative processing goes here
fi
```

The value for 'yesexpr' in the `POSIX` locale (and on English locales on real systems) is `"^[yY]"`. It is to be interpreted as an extended regular expression. See also noexpr.

Comment: Nice. But I seem to be an idiot. Where can I find a list of the arguments that `locale` knows about? The man page on my Mac OS 10.5 box doesn't seem to have them.

Comment: Nice. Could you please link back to the source?

Comment: @dmckee you can do `locale -k LC_MESSAGES` (and for the other LC_whatever), or see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html) for ones defined by the standard. @Daniel what source other than the locale utility page that I did link?

Comment: Great answer, should definitely be the accepted one.

Answer (score 6):

Staying in bash (or any other shell if you display the prompt independently):

```
case $answer in
  [Yy]*) echo Ok;;
  *) echo "Can't you read? I said to say yes.";;
esac
```

This accepts responses like `yn` as yes,  `y` (with an initial space) as no, and `wlkjzuhfod` as no, which may not be optimal but is consistent with typical shell prompts: that's how `rm -i`, `find -ok` and others do it.

This eschews the whole issue of internationalization: in other languages, you would need to translate expected responses. There's no standard shell method then; you can turn to [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/), but then your script will require it to be installed (it's available in many distributions but not always installed by default).

```
if dialog --yesno "Choose yes" 0 0; then …
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use a simple function:

```
Confirm() { read -sn 1 -p "$* [Y/N]? "; [[ ${REPLY:0:1} = [Yy] ]]; }
```

The function just returns `0` if `Y` or `y` is entered and `1` if anything else is entered.
It can be used with `if...fi`:

```
if Confirm "Type y or n"; then
echo "You typed y"
else
echo "You typed n"
fi
```

Or just like this:

```
Confirm "Type y" && echo "You typed y"
```

Comment: Take off the `-s` to have a visual history of what what was typed.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-modified @faif ans

```
YesOrNo() {
        while :
        do
                read -p 'Do you want to Continue (yes/no?): ' answer
                case "${answer}" in
                    [yY]|[yY][eE][sS]) exit 0 ;;
                        [nN]|[nN][oO]) exit 1 ;;
                esac
        done
}


if $( YesOrNo ); then
        echo "Ans is yes.. Do something....."
else
        echo "Ans is No... skip.."
fi
```

**Test**

```
root@ubuntu:~# bash confirm.sh
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?):  # if Blank Enter then ask again
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?):
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?):
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?): no
Ans is No... skip..
root@ubuntu:~# bash confirm.sh
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?):
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?):
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?): ye
Do you want to Continue (yes/no?): yes
Ans is yes.. Do something.....
```